# Are there any module or component for table data type in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I need a component or module that allows me a easy way to enter and show data of products.

Fiewld1| Field2| field3
data1  |  data2|  data3
   .   |    .  |   .
   .   |    .  |   .
   .   |    .  |   .
   .   |    .  |   .
   .   |    .  |   .

Answer (score 0):

Try http://getk2.org/ or http://www.flexicontent.org/

There are others at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction which may help, but those 2 are pretty good.